# Rclone: How to skip copying files if there is already of file with the same name?

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive, rclone

I'm using `rclone` to copy a shared Google Drive folder, but I'm running into a problem: when copying the same folder to the same location over and over again, `rclone` creates new folders each time, each a duplicate to an existing folder in the folder. I believe this is due to the fact that `rclone` only considers two files identical if they match name, hash and mod-time, rather than just name. So, is there a flag I can pass to `rclone` so it will skip based only on identical file names? I tried `--ignore-existing` but it didn't work.

An example: `rclone copy remote:folder_to_copy_from remote: --drive-folder-id=id_of_folder_to_copy_to` copies `folder_to_copy_from/a.txt` to `folder_to_copy_to`, even if `folder_to_copy_to/a.txt` exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently all you needed was `--ignore-existing` at the end.

Comment: Strange that you said you already tried it and it didn't work but now it does. If you figure out what changed, let us know.

Comment: @NetServOps Maybe it's because I removed the `--drive-shared-with-me`?

Comment: `rclone check remote:folder_to_copy_from remote:folder_to_copy_to --size-only --one-way --missing-on-dst A.txt` confirmed this.

Comment: confirmed what? you latest comment showed that you didn't include `--ignore-existing` however you answer said you move it to the end the command; are you saying you replaced `ignore-existing` with `--missing-on-dst`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many files in /path/to/src but only a few of them change every day, you can copy all the files which have changed recently very efficiently like this:

**rclone copy --max-age 24h --no-traverse /path/to/src remote:**

Note: Use the **-P/--progress** flag to view real-time transfer statistics.

Note: Use the **--dry-run** or the **--interactive/-i** flag to test without copying anything.

**rclone copy source:path dest:path [flags]**

Source - https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_copy/

Note that it is always the contents of the directory that is synced, not the directory so when source:path is a directory, it's the contents of source:path that are copied, not the directory name and contents.

If dest:path doesn't exist, it is created and the source:path contents go there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126714/discussion-on-answer-by-netservops-rclone-how-to-skip-copying-files-if-there-is).